# ¿Cómo abrir un CMD y hacer dir C:/Files con Ruby?

Tags: ruby, cmd

Tengo un ejecutable que solo se puede arrancar desde el *CMD*.

El ejecutable está en el directorio **C:**.

¿Cómo lo ejecuto y luego le introduzco *input* para poder repetir el proceso 100 veces desde *NetBeans* en *Ruby*?

Comment: Podrías revisar tu pregunta y editarla para agregar más contexto o alguna otra información que consideres relevante, es díficil proveer una respuesta de la manera en que está

Answer (score 1):

No entiendo si quieres hacer un plugin para netbeans que haga eso, o escribir codigo Ruby usando Netbeans para realizar eso.

Asumire lo segundo, empezando que el detalle de Netbeans esta de mas, ya que podrias hacerlo con cualquier editor de texto.

Para ejecutar comandos de shell en Ruby solo debes encerrar el comando bajo el simobolo de acento grave **( ` )**.

```
(0..100).each do  
  `c:/mi_programa.exe` # Ejecutar este comando en una linea de comandos
  puts ` dir c:/Files ` # Imprimir en pantalla el resultado de hacer dir c:/files
end
```

Comment: PD: No recomiendo usar ruby sobre windows